# Cómo puedo crear una lista en base a otra lista con Getx Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Necesito mostrar mi coleccion1 una lista en mi HomeScreen, voy a mostrar cada registro en un Card, dentro de cada Card quiero mostrar los registros de una segunda coleccion2 en la que guarde el id de la primera coleccion, y dentro de esta segunda Crad se va a mostrar una tercera lista de una tercera coleccion3 donde tengo el id a la que pertenece de la seguna coleccion.

La idea es mostrar 3 Crads una dentro de la otra mostrando los registros a la que pertenecen una de la anterior.

Algo como la imagen a la que esta adjunta.

En la coleccion1 solo tengo: (id, Room) como valores

En la coleccion2 tengo: (id, idRomm, Cab) como valores

En la coleccion3 tengo: (id, idCab, pp) como valores

Necesito hacer en Getx, que cuando se cree cada registro de un (Room) este traiga los registros que tienen ese id del Room que tiene en la coleccion2, y en lo que haga cada registro de la coleccion2 se traiga los valores que tiene en la coleccion3 que contienen el id de la coleccion 2.

Por eso a cada coleccion le inclui el id de la coleccion anterior.

Me pueden ayudar con una idea? Vale destacar que soy nuevo en Dart y Flutter.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]